# Perl CLI code cannot do a string line appended

Tags: perl, command-line-interface

I'm trying to use a `perl -npe` one-liner to surround each line with `=`.

```
$ for i in {1..4}; { echo $i ;} |perl -npe '...'
=1=
=2=
=3=
=4=
```

The following is my first attempt. Note that the line feeds are in the incorrect position.

```
$ for i in {1..4}; { echo $i ;} |perl -npe '$_= "=".$_."=" '
=1
==2
==3
==4
=
```

I tried using `chop` to remove them line feeds and then re-add them in the correct position, but it didn't work.

```
$ for i in {1..4} ;{ echo $i ;} |perl -npe '$_= "=".chop($_)."=\n" '
=
=
=
=
=
=
=
=
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Tip: The same input can be generated using `seq 1 7` or just `seq 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chop` returned the removed character, not the remaining string. It modifies the variable in-place. So the following is the correct usage:

```bash
perl -npe'chop( $_ ); $_ = "=$_=\n"'
```

But we can improve this.

- It's safer to use `chomp` instead of `chop` to remove trailing line feeds.
- `-n` is implied by `-p`, and it's customary to leave it out when `-p` is used.
- `chomp` and `chop` modify `$_` by default, so we don't need to explicitly pass `$_`.

```bash
perl -pe'chomp; $_ = "=$_=\n"'
```

Finally, we can get the same exact behaviour out of `-l`.

```bash
perl -ple'$_ = "=$_="'
```